On the connection between zeros of the Riemann Zeta function and prime numbers - a simple graphical approach
Premise
What follows is a simple approach to understand something more about linking prime numbers and continuous functions / summations by someone who does not know complex analysis but is fascinated by mathematical problems that can be more or less easily described by high school mathematics.
Argumentation
Consider the following
$$ F1 = \sum_{b=Riemann \> zeta \> zeros}^{number \_ of \_ zeros}\left (\sum_{n=1}^{n \_ max} {\frac{cos(b\cdot ln(n))}{n^{a}}} \right )  $$
where $b$ is the imaginary part of the nth zero of the Riemann Zeta function ($b$={$14.134...$,$21.022...$, etc... }). The real part is supposed to be always $0.5$, but not yet proven.
The following image is a plot of $F1$ where I set values for following parameters ($n$ in x-axis, $F1$ in y-axis):

$number \_ of \_ zeros$
$n \_ max$
$a$, that is set equal to $0$.


I created this plot with this cell of SageMathCell service (I've written a simple little not-optimized python script to perform the calculation, script parameters can be changed dynamically).
A few questions about this very dirty approach to find graphically prime numbers



Is today's most effective, fast and accurate formula or procedure in calculating the imaginary part of the zeros of the Riemann zeta function capable of calculating yet another zero without knowing the previous zeros? Or is it necessary to have computed the previous zeros in order to compute each zero?




Are there other functions or summations such as $F1$ that show similar behavior, that is, that show a kind of "mass spectrometer" of natural numbers with peaks at prime numbers and perhaps at other particular numbers such as perfect squares or powers of $2$?




The fact that $F1$ shows the primes in the manner indicated in the graph and with the python script I posted (obviously with different precision and accuracy depending on the number of zeros $number \_ of \_ zeros$ chosen and probably depending on the value of $n \_ max$, but I need to do some testing of this thing I'm curious about because I'm not sure) is because the primes are somehow hidden in the $cos(b*ln(n))$ function when $b$ represents a zero of the Zeta function? In other words, is it the prime numbers that allow the $F1$ function to behave this way or is it the $F1$ function that hides the prime numbers? The first statement makes more sense to me, that is, the existence of the prime numbers and their distribution leads to $F1$ behaving as seen in the graph. I would be inclined to say that proving how the prime numbers are distributed is a possible task only if one adopts a lower level of mathematics than the natural numbers, but I think that does not exist. Riemann found a connection between complex analysis and prime numbers, but I have a hard time believing that one can use complex (or real) analysis to find a direct way to determine the nth prime number with little calculation (let's say I hope so). What do you think?



Edit 1 (after Steven answer about second Chebyshev function)
@Steven Clark: You are right, my first $F1$ definition was too imprecise, it should be (I think):
$$ F1(n1) = \sum_{b=Riemann \> zeta \> zeros [1]}^{Riemann \> zeta \> zeros [m]}\left (\sum_{n=1}^{n1} {\frac{cos(b\cdot ln(n))}{n^{a}}} \right ) $$
and along the x-axis there are all $n1$ values from $1$ to $n \_ max$ parameter of the python script. $Riemann \> zeta \> zeros [m]$ is the vector of all non-trivial positive imaginary part of the zeta zeros, from the first one ($14.134..$) to the last one (m-th) chosen for the graph.
Is not very elegant from a mathematical point of view but it is enough for me, at least if I want to graph something that actually goes to infinity but needs to be represented in a limited portion of the natural numbers. Thank you for noting the inaccuracy in the notation and definition of $F1$.
As said in my comment after your answer, I will study what you wrote (I don't know anything about Chebyshev). This topic is getting me interested, unfortunately I'm starting off lame because I'm not a mathematician. The primes numbers are too exciting, even for an amateur like me.
Going back to $F1$, I will plot some single waves (i.e. $F0(n1)=\sum_{n=1}^{n1} {\frac{cos(b\cdot ln(n))}{n^{a}}}$ with one single value for $b$) in order to see if there is a tendency of $F0$ to show negative values (with high absolute value) at prime numbers on x-axis, which would lead me to guess that by summing them I get the deepest peaks of $F1$ when I sum several $F0$ waves computed with different individual values of $b$ ($a$ is always set equal to $0$; $a$ is most related to Riemann Hyp, problem that transcends my understanding).
In other words, if intuition is not playing tricks on me (it's a pretty simple intuition anyway), I would expect that only with values of $b$ equal to the imaginary part of the zeros of the Riemann zeta function would the value of $F0$ at the prime numbers along x-axis be the lowest value on average.
As always I will try to look at it graphically, since that is the only thing I am able to do.
Edit 2 (just to fix the issue)
$F1$ posted at beginning and in Edit 1 is a previous graphical experiment performed with the script, I wanted to describe the simpler form but I had the more complex one in my head, the original script showed the function that you later suggested to me.
So $F1$ is showed in following image (SageMathCell code):

but on $F1$ I still have to think about it, so I don't worry for now.
The function I wanted to show (the first original script is ok for it) is
$$ F(n) = \sum_{b=Riemann \> zeta \> zeros [1]}^{Riemann \> zeta \> zeros [m]} {\frac{cos(b\cdot ln(n))}{n^{a}}} $$
Clearly about the behavior of $F(n)$ I remain fascinated by the intriguing connection between prime numbers and zeros of the Riemann zeta function, after all $cos(b*ln(n))$ is such a short but at the same time interesting when one sums it several times with different values of the imaginary part of zeta-zeros, at least to me.
I performed a test to see if along primes the average trend of $F(n)$ is the minimum trend. The graph is following (SageMathCell code):

in which red is $F(n)$ and blue is $F(n=primes)$. One can choose to use $b$ equal to imaginary part of Riemann zeta-zeros or to use random values for $b$. Just to show visually (with plots and not mathematically) this sort of order when using the zeros of the Riemann zeta function and to show an example of the average trend of $F(n)$ when $n=primes$ that seems to be the minimum average trend compared to other natural numbers sequence, random or not (it is related to my last curiosity at the end of my Edit 1). I'm not interested in demonstration (I wouldn't even know where to start), I just like to see, in limited portions of the graph, interesting trends in various things I study generally.
My next goal is to derive a data set with which I can somehow figure out if there can be a connection between nth prime number and number of zeros of the zeta function to be used in the sum of the waves $F(n)$ so that the nth prime number has a peak with a constant absolute amplitude.
Edit 3 (@StevenClark: how I simply obtained the trigonometric formula $cos(b*ln(n))$)
I don't want to bore anyone, I am absolutely sure that the trigonometric formula was already well known. The thing that surprised me was that while playing around with this ‘simple’ function, I tried to add up the various waves using $b$ values equal to the imaginary part of the zeros of the zeta function and the peaks at the prime numbers jumped out. Steven showed me where it came from.
I simply wrote
$$\zeta{(s) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}}}$$
with:
$${s = {a + \mathit{ib}}}$$
with Euler formula
$$ e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x) $$
and obtained
$$ \zeta{(a+ib) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{a+ib}}}} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left (  \frac{cos(b\cdot ln(n))}{n^{a}}-i\cdot \frac{sin(b\cdot ln(n))}{n^{a}} \right ) $$
and I chose the real part with $cos$ to start studying the summation. I believe it is the same with the $sin$ function due to the great similarity between the two functions.
After some numerical experiments, it seemed quite evident to me (always supported by intuition, never by rigorous demonstrations) that there was something interesting inside the trigonometric function $cos(b*ln(n))$ related to prime numbers, thanks to the incredible work of Riemann. I repeat that these kinds of problems should be approached with complex analysis, but like a child I wanted to understand something more with the few tools at my disposal.
I specify that my intention was to determine formulations that were as simple as possible to write and that had a connection with prime numbers. Formulations that presented coefficients or functions, even variable and complex ones, but outside of a periodic (trigonometric) function, gave me the idea of being only more difficult, without giving me quick evidence of the hidden presence of the prime numbers inside them.
I ask:

If my approach is wrong, why?
Why is it more appropriate to start from the explicit formula of Chebyshev's second function, like in $(1)$ in Steven answer?
About second graph of my Edit 2, by using the $(2)$ or $(4)$ formulation of @Steven's very exhaustive answer or the simpler function $F(n)$, which number sequence of natural numbers could have the greatest ‘specific weight’, i.e. the envelope line of the maximum peaks of the functions above running along all the natural numbers? Based on what you @Steven have explained to me, it is normal to see the minimum peaks where there are primes (actually, it is still not entirely clear to me), but the maximum peaks could correspond to some sequence of natural numbers? Intuitively, I would say the natural numbers $2^{n}$, because they are "furthest" from the prime numbers sequence. Mere curiosity.

Since I have other questions on this topic, what should I normally do? Can I continue to post here (with progressive edits), just to have a single reference for my questions?
The questions that come to mind are always about the connection between functions/sums and prime numbers (possibly other sequences of numbers). My approach is very basic, not sophisticated but more inspired by general concepts and speculative investigation.
For those who are interested, I found a discussion not really related to my interest on mathoverflow, link, where there is an answer by Oscar Lanzi showing a strange method for finding prime numbers using the zeta function. It seems to me that up to now, at the level of analysis, prime numbers are only connected to the zeta function and vice versa. Is it true? Of course there is the Eratostene sieve, for example, but it is a pure recursive/iterative algorithm.

Try plotting $$1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} \lim\limits_{K\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} \cos\left(\log(x), \Im\left(\rho_k\right)\right)$$ where $\rho_k$ is a non-trivial zeta-zero and you'll see there's a peak at each prime-power. This assumes the Riemann hypothesis and is related to the derivative of the explicit formula for the second Chebyshev function $$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \Lambda(n)$$.

Note $841=29^2$ in your plot is a prime power which is why the magnitude of its related peak is smaller than the other peaks which are all related to primes.

Ok, I will try to plot the function you proposed, thanks. About $F1$, what inside the double summation of $cos(b*ln(n))$ for many $n$ and $b$ allows to see the peaks for primes and other peaks (with lower amplitude) for other kind of natural numbers, like for example squares of primes? Is there any other law that explains this? And can we be sure that the peaks of greatest amplitude always correspond to the prime numbers?

Your linked Sage code is a mess. You seem to have two implementations of the inner sum where the first one is the for loop over $x$ which doesn't seem to have any effect. Your linked Sage code also doesn't seem to match your plot since the zeta zero slider in the code only goes up to $1000$ and your plot shows the zeta zero slider set at $20000$. Your updated formula evaluated with Mathematica also doesn't seem to match the result of your Sage code when both are evaluated over the first $100$ zeta zeros.

As near as I can tell, your Sage code seems to evaluate similar to $$\sum_{b=1}^m \cos\left(\Im\left(\rho_b\right), \log(n1)\right).$$

Hi Steven, thanks for your feedback. My code is not very clean, but I'm pretty sure it is ok for what I want to represent. I know the image I posted is not equal to first image that appears when one runs the code, user should change also $xmin$ and $xmax$ values to focus on area of interest along x-axis. I will try function proposed by you to perform comparison with $F1$. Function $F0$ I posted could be written as a continuous function by using a simple approach with integrals, but I think only if I use $a=1/2$ and $b$ equal to Riemann zeros (not proven, only supposed).

I add also user can change values in line 6 of script if wants to extend or change the limits of parameters values.

@StevenClark, Hi sorry, after looking again at my script (to perform some other visual experiments) and what I posted here at beginning, I realized that I described one thing but the script shows another thing. Basically I had a “brain disconnection", $F1$ is certainly not the function represented in my first graph. I had done some experiments on some summations previously, and I lost the focus for a moment.

Your formulas are distorting the true relationship between the non-trivial zeta-zeros and the prime-powers. Formulas (1) and (2) in my answer below are the correct formulas  (and also formula (4) assuming the RH). The reason for the peaks at the prime-powers in your formulas is the similarity of the $\cos$ function in your formulas to the $\cos$ function in formula (4) in my answer below. I suggest you focus on studying the correct formulas instead of distorted versions of them.

@StevenClark, Hi and thank you for your explanations and for answering my curiosities, in a schematic way with respect to my three questions.

I tried to follow your calculations and among other things I don't understand why the trigonometric formula in $(4)$ comes out only by assuming Riemann hypotheses, while the $(2)$ doesn't need it. What does it mean? That formula $(4)$ which contains the trigonometric function is obtained only by assuming that all zeros of the zeta function have the real part equal to $1/2$?
I obtained the trig formulation $cos(b*ln(n))$ rewriting the zeta function in real part and imaginary part (the sine function appears in the imaginary part).

I know my approach is wrong, because one must use analytical continuation. But my original intent was to see if there was a connection in the apparently simple function $cos(b*ln(n))$ with the prime numbers, through the zeros of the Riemann zeta function. I did some experiments (rather simple) and after a few attempts I saw this behavior, which you explained analytically. But not everything is clear to me yet.

Formula (4) in my answer below assumes the Riemann hypothesis because it is based on formula (3) in my answer below which substituted $\frac{1}{2}$ for $\Re(\rho_k)$.

Trying to understand what you wrote, several questions came to my mind. I would like to convince myself that the negative peaks corresponding to the primes increase indefinitely. From some tests I saw that as $n_max$ increases, and at the same time $number_of_zeros$ increase (in order to avoid lose accuracy in identifying the peaks), the peaks seem to follow an asymptotic average trend, similar to logarithmic law.
For now I'm more interested in the average behavior of $F(n)$ in my Edit 2 as $n_max$ and $number_of_zeros$ increase.

But I obtained $cos(b*ln(n))$ without assuming it. Or did I assume it was true without realizing it? I simply used Euler's formula.

Assuming the RH one has $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{x^{\rho_k}}{\rho_k}+\frac{x^{\rho_{-k}}}{\rho_{-k}}\right)=x^{\rho_k-1}+x^{\rho_{-k}-1}=2, x^{-1/2}, \cos\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right), \log(x)\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}, \cos\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right), \log(x)\right).$$ WIthout the RH one has $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{x^{\rho_k}}{\rho_k}+\frac{x^{\rho_{-k}}}{\rho_{-k}}\right)=x^{\rho_k-1}+x^{\rho_{-k}-1}=2, x^{\Re\left(\rho_k\right)-1}, \cos\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right), \log(x)\right).$$

@StevenClark, yes, it is now clear to me. Thanks. Let's say that here what is really related to prime numbers, however, seems to me to be the trigonometric function, not the power of $x$ at the beginning of formula, in the case of reasoning independent of Riemann's hypothesis. I believe the quantity in front of the cosine determines the amplitude of the peaks, not where they are located along natural numbers.

I'll edit my post to show how I obtain the $cos(b*ln(n))$ function. I will certainly accept your answer, which is of great interest to me and has aroused my curiosity, but I would first like to ask a few more questions in order to go a little deeper into this subject, which is of great interest to me at the moment.

Of course feel free to answer, according to your free time.

This answer addresses your three questions but in reverse order.

Question (3):

The explicit formula for the second Chebyshev function is
$$\psi_o(x)=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{\psi(x-\epsilon)+\psi(x+\epsilon)}{2}\right)\\=x-\lim\limits_{K\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \left(\frac{x^{\rho_k}}{\rho_k}+\frac{x^{\rho_{-k}}}{\rho_{-k}}\right)\right)-\log(2\,\pi)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{-2\,n}}{2\,n}\\=x-\lim\limits_{K\to\infty}  \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \left(\frac{x^{\rho_k}}{\rho_k}+\frac{x^{\rho_{-k}}}{\rho_{-k}}\right)\right)-\log(2\,\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\,\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right),\qquad x>1\tag{1}$$
where $\rho_k$ is a non-trivial zeta-zero in the upper-half plane, $\rho_{-k}=1-\rho_k$, and $\Im\left(\rho_k\right)$ increases as $k$ increases.

The first order derivative of formula (1) above is
$$\psi_o'(x)=\frac{\delta\, \psi_o(x)}{\delta x}=1-\lim\limits_{K\to\infty}  \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \left(x^{\rho_k-1}+x^{\rho_{-k}-1}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{x-x^3}\tag{2}$$

Assuming the Riemann hypothesis
$$x^{\rho_k-1}+x^{\rho_{-k}-1}=x^{1/2+i\, \Im\left(\rho_k\right)-1}+x^{1/2-\Im\left(\rho_k\right)-1}=x^{-1/2}\, \left(x^{i\, \Im\left(\rho_k\right)}+x^{-i\, \Im\left(\rho_k\right)}\right)\\=x^{-1/2}\, \left(e^{i\, \log(x)\, \Im\left(\rho_k\right)}+e^{-i\, \log(x)\, \Im\left(\rho_k\right)}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\, \cos\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right)\, \log(x)\right)\tag{3}$$
and consequently the first-order derivative of formula (1) above can be evaluated as
$$\psi_o'(x)=\frac{\delta\, \psi_o(x)}{\delta x}=1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\, \underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \cos\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right)\, \log(x)\right)\right)+\frac{1}{x-x^3}\tag{4}$$
where the sum is only over the non-trivial zeta-zeros in the upper-half plane.

The second Chebyshev function
$$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \Lambda(n)=\sum\limits_{p^k\le x} \log(p) \tag{5}$$
takes a step of $\log(p)$ when $n=p^k$ is a prime-power.

Formula (4) above for $\psi_o'(x)$ is an analytic representation of
$$\psi'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n)\, \delta(x-n)=\sum\limits_{p^j} \log(p)\, \delta(x-n) \tag{6}$$
which explains the peaks of $\psi_o'(x)$ defined in formula (4) above when $n=p^j$ is a prime-power.

Your formula for $F1$ doesn't make much sense to me because there's no $x$ in it related to the horizontal-axis of your plot. You indicate "$n$ in x axis", but this doesn't make sense because you've overloaded $n$ as both a sum index and the horizontal-axis variable. Your updated formula for $F1(n1)$ where you distinguished $n1$ from $n$ also doesn't seem to be correct. As near as I can tell, your Sage code seems to evaluate equivalent to
$$F1(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \cos\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right)\, \log(x)\right)\tag{7}$$
where $\rho_k$ is the $k^{th}$ non-trivial zeta-zero in the upper-half plane (see Figure (1) below), but I suggest you focus instead on formula (4) for $\psi_o'(x)$ above which assuming the Riemann hypothesis is the correct relationship.

Try evaluating your Sage code over the first $1000$ non-trivial zeta-zeros in the upper-half plane and compare the result to Figure (1) below which illustrates the corresponding discrete plot of formula (7) for $F1(x)$ above evaluated at $K=1000$.


Figure (1): Illustration of formula (7) for $F1(x)$ evaluated at $K=1000$

Note that
$$-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[\psi (x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty \psi(x)\, x^{-s-1}\, dx\,,\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{8}$$
and
$$\psi(x)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s\, \zeta(s)}\right]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{\alpha-i \infty}^{\alpha+i \infty} \left(-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right)\, \frac{x^s}{s}\, ds\,,\quad\alpha>1\tag{9}.$$

Formula (1) above is derived from the residues of $\left(-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right)\, \frac{x^s}{s}$ (which is the integrand in formula (9) above) at its poles which correspond to the zeta-zeros and $s\in\{0,1\}$.

Question (2):

Here are a couple of other example formulas.

Try evaluating
$$\lim\limits_{N,f\to\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{f} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)\, \log(n)}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{f n}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\tag{10}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and the evaluation frequency $f$ is assumed to be a positive integer and you'll see it converges exactly to $\log(p)$ at prime-powers $x=p^j$ and to zero at other integer values of $x$ when $0<x\le N$. This formula is related to another analytic representation of $\psi(x)$ and its corresponding first-order derivative $\psi'(x)$.

Or try evaluating
$$\lim\limits_{N,f\to\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{f} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)\, \nu(n)}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{f n}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\tag{11}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, $\nu(n)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $n$ (see OEIS Entry A001221), and the evaluation frequency $f$ is once again assumed to be a positive integer and you'll see it converges exactly to $1$ at prime-powers $x=p^j$ and to zero at other integer values of $x$ when $0<x\le N$.
This second formula is related to an analytic representation of the prime-power counting function $K(x)=\sum\limits_{p^j\le x} 1$ and its corresponding first-order derivative $K'(x)$.

There are also other explicit formulas for L-functions involving sums over the zeta-zeros that can be differentiated analogous to formula (1) for $\psi_o(x)$ above. For example see formula (7) at Riemann Prime Counting Function.

Question (1):

I don't believe it's necessary to know the values of all the zeta-zeros $\rho_k$ for which $\left|\Im(\rho_k)\right|<t$ to calculate the next zeta-zero for which $\left|\Im(\rho_k)\right|>t$. For example the non-trivial zeta-zero counting function can be approximated as
$$N(t)=\sum\limits_{0<\Im(\rho)<t} 1=\frac{t}{2 \pi}\left(\log\left(\frac{t}{2 \pi}\right)-1\right)+\frac{7}{8}+s(t)+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right),\quad t\geq 2\tag{12}$$
where $s(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arg\left(\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right)$.


Thank you Steven for your time to explain the formula you suggested. Since I do not practice mathematics every day, I will spend some time to fully understand what you have written. I am updating my first post to extend more about my contents; I find no smarter way to update the content I wrote than to edit my first post, instead to write comments or to add new posts.

Looks like a forex price signal!

I'm pretty sure the two graphs are the same, in my dirty python script I simply introduced some interactive parameters like $xmax$, $xmin$, ecc... to change area of view. I know $xmax$ for example should be equal to $n_max$, would be smarter. But these things I don't worry about now. I am actually mostly interested in the three questions that I posted in my first post.

By changing $n_max$ and $number _ of _ zeros$ (and contextually also $xmin$, $xmax$, $ymin$ and $ymax$), user could see that the larger $n_max$ is, the larger $number _ of _ zeros$ must be in order to see the peaks well, i.e., user loses accuracy, logically, the farther user goes toward large numbers unless user uses more waves to sum, I expected this but I would like to understand what math law user can use to link $n_max$ and $number _ of _ zeros$ so that there is no loss of accuracy in the peaks at the prime numbers as $n_max$ increases.

@Matteo Formula (4) in may answer above converges (in a distributional sense) to formula (6) in my answer above as $K\to\infty$, and the peaks at each prime-power get taller and narrower as $K\to\infty$ with the area under each peak approximating the step-size of $\psi(x)$ at the corresponding prime-power.

@Matteo The magnitude of the peak at each prime-power goes to $\infty$ as $K\to\infty$, so your comment above how large $K$ must be to avoid losing accuracy is misguided. However, it is true as $x$ increases the peaks at larger prime-powers are less well formed than the peaks at smaller prime-powers since formula (4) in my answer above only converges as $K\to\infty$.

I followed a similar trigonometric approach and used the  $\tan(x)$ function. Instead of summation, I used an integral. The result is neat but not widely accepted as of now. You can see the preprints in my Vixra and ResearchGate under the same name:

"Riemann Hypothesis Proof"
"Analyzing the Connection from ( H(z) ) to the Riemann Zeta Function"

Here is the MATLAB code snippet I used:
% Define the range of values for n
n = 1:200;

% Initialize an array to store the results
result = zeros(size(n));

% Compute the values of the expression for each value of n
for k = 1:length(n)
    primeCount(k) = sum(isprime(1:n(k)));  % Compute the prime counting function using isprime function
    result(k) = log(sec(pi * primeCount(end))); % Compute the expression ln(sec(pi * nlog(n)))
end

% Display the results
plot(imag(result))


The plot shows the imaginary part of the results from the logarithmic secant function applied to the prime counting function. I’m looking for feedback or any insights on this approach.
What I noticed is that whenever the slope is positive, it peaks to the value of constant $ \pi $ at primes. Conversely, whenever the slope is negative, it's value goes to zero, also at primes, generating the prime sequences.
Which all motivated me to investigate further as in the two preprints.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@OussamaBasta, hi thank you for your example, I will translate your code in python and will perform some experiments on it. I am mainly interested in simple functions/sums that do not use complex mathematics (four operations, power elevation and some transcendental functions). Complex mathematics is too complex for someone like me who has no solid knowledge: I don't understand it and I would have to convince myself to prove a formula backwards from the starting axioms or other theorems or formulas that have already been proved, and I don't know how to do.

@OussamaBasta, can you briefly describe the argumentation that led you to get the formulation you proposed?
